# How can I identify when the aws cdk app is running in the deployment state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code

I have the following problem:

I have a stack created and after the resource has been created (specifically a rabbitmq broker with Amazon MQ) I want to configure some stuff that cannot be done with cdk and has to be done via an REST api call.

The thing is I just want to do the rest api call only in the deployment state once the broker is up and running and the rabbitmq_url is resolved.

I have something like the following, but is not working as expected:

```py
# Doc Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-amazonmq-broker.html
rabbitmq_broker = amazonmq. \
    CfnBroker(self, "RabbitMQBroker",
              broker_name=f"{os.getenv('ENVIRONMENT_NAME')}-rabbitmq",
              engine_type="RABBITMQ",
              engine_version="3.8.17",
              deployment_mode="SINGLE_INSTANCE",
              host_instance_type="mq.t3.micro",
              subnet_ids=[[public_subnet.subnet_id for public_subnet in vpc.public_subnets][0]],
              logs=amazonmq.CfnBroker.LogListProperty(general=True),
              # This means we can access rabbitmq from internet without going into the VPC
              publicly_accessible=True,
              users=[amazonmq.CfnBroker.UserProperty(username=os.getenv('RABBITMQ_USER'),
                                                     password=os.getenv('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD'))],
              auto_minor_version_upgrade=True)

rabbitmq_url = f"{rabbitmq_broker.ref}.mq.{os.getenv('CDK_DEFAULT_REGION')}.amazonaws.com"

...

# Only executed when the token is resolved in the deploy stage
if not core.Token.is_unresolved(rabbitmq_broker.ref):
# Create virtual host 'kmhbackend' via RabbitMQ Management HTTP API
    response = requests.post(f"https://{rabbitmq_url}:15671/api/vhosts/kmhbackend",
                          auth=(os.getenv('RABBITMQ_USER'), os.getenv('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD')),
                          headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})

    if response.status_code != requests.codes.get('created'):
        Log.error("Warning: The virtual host has not been created")
        print("Warning: The virtual host has not been created")
```

How can I identify when cdk app is running in the deployment state?

I woudn't like to have to use a context variable only to identify this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well you can always wait for your stack to finish it's entire deployment and then maybe perform the API call?

Comment: @DebdutGoswami, what do you mean to wait the entire deployment to finish, to execute first cdk deploy and then execute some other scripts to configure the left things? In that way it would kind of loose the sense of Iac, since I would need to execute manually after each deploy or to create a lambda that will listen for events but it would be kind of a pain to do it in that way

Comment: You are absolutely right but I simply suggested a way around since I could not locate anything even remotely similar in cdk documentation. Maybe I am just looking with wrong keywords. You can instead go ahead and raise a feature request in their github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading the documentation in deep, the solution is to create a custom resource in a new nested stack and add a dependency between the 2 stacks, so the custom resource will wait for the initial resource to be completely deployed.

So the solution is like this:

```py
class MessageBrokerConfigStack(core.NestedStack):
    """
    This stack will take of configure rabbitmq once it's created by API calls

    * the RabbitMQ Management HTTP API at 'rabbitmq-web-console:15671' ,
    docs of API can be found in rabbitmq_url/api/index.html

    Warning: In the docs the port used for the RabbitMQ Management HTTP API is 15672,
    but with AWS the port to be used is 15671
    """

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str,
                 vpc: ec2.Vpc, rabbit_broker_url: str,
                 rabbitmq_user: str, rabbitmq_password: str,
                 **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
    
        ...
        onEvent = lambda_. \
        Function(self, "CR_RabbitMQ_configurator_handler",
                 function_name="cr_cdk_rabbitmq_configurator_handler",
                 description="Function that will handle all the configuration for rabbitmq broker created by cdk",
                 runtime=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
                 layers=[layer],
                 handler="config_rabbitmq.lambda_handler",
                 code=lambda_.Code.from_asset('aws_lambda/lambdas')
                 )

    config_rabbitmq_provider = cr.Provider(self, 'CR_RabbitMQ_configurator_provider',
                                           vpc=vpc,
                                           vpc_subnets=ec2.SubnetSelection(subnet_type=ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE),
                                           on_event_handler=onEvent)

    # Will create a custom resource in cloudformation, this custom resource is compose by a lambda that
    # will contain a function and this function will handle the different events
    # ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/apps.html#lifecycle
    # ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_custom
    config_rabbitmq = core.CustomResource(self, 'CR_RabbitMQ_configurator',
                                          service_token=config_rabbitmq_provider.service_token,
                                          properties={
                                              "rabbitmq_url": rabbit_broker_url,
                                              "rabbit_user": rabbitmq_user,
                                              "rabbit_password": rabbitmq_password
                                          })
```

Then the lambda code will listen for the events and execute the desired actions.

```py
import requests


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """
    This method is the native input for AWS Lambda
    """

    print("lambda rabbitmq received")
    print(event)
    print(context)

    props = event['ResourceProperties']
    rabbitmq_url = props['rabbitmq_url']
    rabbit_user = props['rabbit_user']
    rabbit_password = props['rabbit_password']

    print(rabbitmq_url)
    print(rabbit_user)
    print(rabbit_password)

    if event["RequestType"] == "Create":
        # ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/apps.html#lifecycle
        # ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_custom
        # Only executed when the token is resolved in the deploy stage
        # Create virtual host 'kmhbackend' via RabbitMQ Management HTTP API
        response = requests.put(f"https://{rabbitmq_url}:15671/api/vhosts/new_virtual_host",
                                auth=(rabbit_user, rabbit_password),
                                headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})

        print("response from rabbitmq:")
        print(response)

        if response.status_code != requests.codes.get('created'):
            print("Warning: The virtual host has not been created")
```

Then on the parent stack we just need to do

```py
resource = Resource(....)

configResource = ConfigResouce(...)

configResource.add_dependency(resource)
```